# How to achieve this animation in react-native

Tags: react-native, animation

I want to achieve this effect in react-native, Is there a component that achieves this or can this can be done using Animated View ?

[image]

I want to only to create the custom tab component, with this sliding animation when switching between them

Answer (score 0):

If you mean TopTabs and use [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) to navigate around your app you can use the [TopTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/) from react-native. Otherwise this can be done with React Animated

Comment: I mean the Underline Animation how it moves between tabs

Comment: Oh yeah you have to use Animated then it shouldn't be that hard. Probably two Views one in the other, children view has 1/4 (as example with 4 tabs) of its parents width and then just animate translateX of the view to its width times 1/2/3/4.